# Is legal use initializer_list to initialize an object with derived types?

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11, initializer-list, object-slicing

Well, maybe from the title is not clear what I'm actually asking.

I have a class with an initializer-list constructor `std::initializer_list<B>`. Is legal initialize it with an initializer list of objects of class `D`, where `D` is derived from `B`?

```
#include <initializer_list>

struct B {
    B(int) {}
};

struct D: public B {
    D(int s): B(s) {}
};

struct Foo {
    Foo(std::initializer_list<B> l) {}
};

void main() {
    Foo    f{ D{ 1 }, D{ 2 } };
}
```

If is not legal, is that ill-formed? or just undefined behavior?

I've tried that code in Visual Studio 2013 Update 1. It compiles, but when I run it, I can see (debugging) how:

1. An object of class `D` is created for the first object `D{1}` (let call `tempD1`). `D` constructor is invoked and then the `B` constructor.
2. The base of `tempD1` is moved to a new `B` object (`tmpB1`): `B` move constructor is invoked.
3. The same for the second object `D{2}` (`tmpD2`, `tmpB2`).
4. `Foo` initializer-list constructor is invoked. All fine at this point.
5. destructor of `tmpB2` is invoked once.
6. destructor of `tmpD2` is invoked **twice**.
7. destructor of `tmpD1` is invoked once.

I guess is a bug of the compiler (calling one destructor twice and missing the other one). But I'm not sure if that use of std::initializer_list is legal yet.

(Fixed the confusions about 'D' or 'A' name)

Comment: That can't possibly compile. `std::initializer_list` is a template, not a type.

Comment: You might want to decide whether to call your class/objects `A` or `D` because it is kind of confusing this way

Comment: Also, [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), please.

Comment: @KerrekSB: After fix some typos, now it compiles in VC++2013.

Comment: @jrok: I had a sample but trying to simplify more I left some mistakes. Not it's fixed.

Comment: To use Ds as Bs without slicing, you need to access them via pointers (or better, smart pointers).

Comment: @YoungJohn References are equally polymorphic and are preferable to any kind of pointer, if pointers are unnecessary - which in many cases they are. There's a weird idea that goes around that not only pointers, but worse, dynamic allocation, are required for polymorphism. That's not true.

Comment: @underscore_d references are not sufficient for ownership + polymorphism, however

Comment: @Caleth I don't see how ownership is relevant here. Polymorphism and ownership are orthogonal concepts. And of course, the owner of an object may give out references to it, so long as the recipient won't try to use that reference after the lifetime of the object has ended.

Comment: @underscore_d Foo will *often* be owning the B's that are passed to its constructor, outside of minimal example code

Comment: @Caleth Let me rephrase: I don't see how made-up scenarios that were not mentioned in the question are relevant to the question.

Comment: @underscore_d that is a fair point, you can (and most often should) use references instead of pointers for polymorphism. Pointers or references both will avoid the problem of slicing that occurs when using values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The conversion from `std::initializer_list<D>` to `std::initializer_list<B>` is not valid... 
But construct a `std::initializer_list<B>` with some `D` is valid (and it is what happens here)...

But you will have [object slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing)

Comment: Strange: slicing is not considered a narrowing conversion.. (then again, it's just binding to a const ref of a base class type)

Comment: Good point the note about slicing. That is something I've realized before but is not a problem for me (not using data members in derived class).

Comment: But I'm not sure there is a `std::initializer_list<D>` to `std::initializer_list<B>` conversion. In this example might be but, what happens if I use two different derived classes `D1` and `D2` of base class? `Foo f{D1{1},D2{2.3}};` is still valid (I think so)? In such case, not `initializer_list` of derived class is possible.

Comment: @Gonmator: Yes, there is not `std::initializer_list<D>`. The slicing happens directly in this case. So `Foo f{D1{}, D2{}}` is still valid.